# FileUpload.FileContent pierde su contenido tras ser enviado en correo

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, fileupload

Tengo este código para realizar un preview de la imagen tras usar el FileUpload control en asp.net , pero cuando envío el mensaje usando el otro boton envía el correo con la informacion correcta pero el archivo adjunto pierde su 'contenido' , a que me refiero : El archivo adjunto pesa originalmente 10mb , y cuando lo envía por correo pesa 253bytes

Boton para realizar el Preview de la Imagen, guardo el contenido del Fileupload en un session para que no se pierda tras un PostBack

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                HttpPostedFile postedfile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                int filesize = postedfile.ContentLength;

                if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
                {
                    Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
                    int Tamanio = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                    byte[] ImagenOriginal = new byte[Tamanio];

                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(ImagenOriginal, 0, Tamanio);

                    Bitmap ImagenoriginalBinaria = new Bitmap(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

                    string ImagenDataUrl64 = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ImagenOriginal);

                    ImgPreview.ImageUrl = ImagenDataUrl64;
                    LblFileupload.Text = filename;

                }

                else
                {
                    MensajeJQ("Solo imagenes en Formato Imagen JPG - JPEG - PNG", "Aviso del Sistema");
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
```

Boton para enviar el e-mail

```
 protected void BtnSi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Boolean correcto = false;
            try
            {
                if (Session["FileUpload1"].ToString()=="")
                {
                    MensajeJQ("Por favor Adjunte un Archivo", "Aviso del Sistema"); return;
                }

                else
                {
                    FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)Session["FileUpload1"];

                    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile postedfile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedfile.FileName);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                        int filesize = postedfile.ContentLength;

                        if (filesize > 10000000)
                        {
                            MensajeJQ("El archivo no puede pesar más de 10mb", "Aviso del Sistema");
                            return;
                        }

                        if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png")
                        {
                            BtnSi.Enabled = false;
                            BtnNo.Enabled = false;

                            DataSet Tableform = new DataSet();
                            Tableform = Obj.Ws_Usp_Up_Solicitudes(8, TxtSolicitud.Text, Session["0"].ToString(), "", "");
                            MailMessage myMailMessage = new MailMessage();
                            string fromAddress = Crypt.Crypto.Decrypt(GraphicText.GraphicText.SvrApp.StrCorreo);
                            string toAddress = Tableform.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            string mailServer = Crypt.Crypto.Decrypt(GraphicText.GraphicText.SvrApp.StrServer);
                            myMailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
                            myMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
                            myMailMessage.Subject = Tableform.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
                            myMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                            myMailMessage.Body = Tableform.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                            myMailMessage.CC.Add(Tableform.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString());
                            myMailMessage.Bcc.Add(Tableform.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString());


                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                            Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment(FileUpload1.FileContent, fileName);

                            myMailMessage.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
                            SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(mailServer);

                            HttpFileCollection fc = Request.Files;



                            mySmtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Crypt.Crypto.Decrypt(GraphicText.GraphicText.SvrApp.StrUser), Crypt.Crypto.Decrypt(GraphicText.GraphicText.SvrApp.StrPss));
                            mySmtpClient.Port = 25;
                            mySmtpClient.Send(myMailMessage);


                           // MensajeJQ("Confirmación Enviada Correctamente", "Aviso del Sistema");

                            Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl("~") + @"SolicitudesIngresadas/MenuTomaFirmas.aspx");

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            MensajeJQ("Solo imagenes en Formato Imagen JPG - JPEG - PNG", "Aviso del Sistema");
                            return;
                        }

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        MensajeJQ("Por favor Adjunte un Archivo", "Aviso del Sistema"); return;
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

Comment: O sea si el archivo es de 10mb estas poniendo eso en Session, eso es una locura

Comment: Perdón por la mala práctica ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se presenta porque quieres asignar un componente a la Session, cuando usas

```
Session["FileUpload1"] = FileUpload1;
```

no va a resultar, eso no debes realizarlo, lo que debes poner es el `byte array` que seria el archivo seleccionado en session

```
byte[] input = new byte[fileLen - 1];
input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
Session["FileUpload1"] = input;
```

[FileUpload.FileBytes Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes?view=netframework-4.8)

Cuando envies el mail tendras el `byte[]` en Session listo, sin necesidad de usar el FileUpload nuevamente

Comment: Al final lo que hice fue usar JavaScript para previsualizar la imagen y no perder el contenido del FileUpload tras un postback, pero marcaré tu respuesta como correcta por si a alguien en algun momento le resulta útil